# Heroic leader after his unit is eliminated

Tags: memoir-44

If the unit with the *heroic leader* dies but no star is rolled, does the enemy still get one victory medal for the destroyed infantry unit?

[Action Cards 8 - Heroic Leader](http://www.daysofwonder.com/memoir44/en/content/cards_compendium/?id=action_8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! Both the infantry unit just eliminated **and** the Heroic Leader are worth a Victory Medal, as the only meaningful interpretation of the bullet point on the card itself (my emphasis):

> When infantry unit with a heroic leader is eliminated, roll two Battle
>   dice; if at least 1 star is rolled, **leader is lost and counts as a
>   Victory Medal**; if heroic leader survives, move him to nearest friendly
>   infantry unit.

There is no mention of the destroyed infantry unit **not** counting as a Victory medal, so that must be taken as unchanged from the standard rule. Clearly then the destruction of the heroic leader, either through a star being rolled or [through there not being a friendly infantry unit to relocate to](http://www.daysofwonder.com/memoir44/en/content/cards_compendium/?id=action_8), counts as an additional Victory medal.